# Set Different Layout Manager for Single RecylerView with multiple ViewTypes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in my Activity.It's orientation is Vertical.I have two different `ViewTypes` for RecyclerView item. When the API response is `JSONArray` I need to set the entry in RecyclerView with `CardViews` and LayoutManager as a Horizontal.
This is code for my EntryType

```
public abstract class ChatObject {
    public static final int INPUT_OBJECT = 0;
    public static final int RESPONSE_OBJECT = 1;
    public static final int FOODIE_CARDS = 2;

    private String text;
    private String name, phone, city;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(@NonNull String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public abstract int getType();
}
```

This is code for my BaseViewHolder

```
public abstract class BaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public BaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public abstract void OnBindView(ChatObject object);
```

This is code for ChatAdapter

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ChatObject> chatObjects;

    public ChatAdapter(ArrayList<ChatObject> chatObjects){
        this.chatObjects=chatObjects;
    }
    @Override
    public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView;
        switch (viewType){
            case ChatObject.INPUT_OBJECT:
                itemView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.input,parent,false);
                return  new ChatInputView(itemView);
            case ChatObject.RESPONSE_OBJECT:
                itemView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.response_text,parent,false);
                return new ChatOutputView(itemView);
            case ChatObject.FOODIE_OBJECT:
                itemView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.foodie_detail,parent,false);
                return new FoodieView(itemView);
            default:
                itemView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.response_text,parent,false);
                return  new ChatOutputView(itemView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.OnBindView(chatObjects.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return chatObjects.get(position).getType();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chatObjects.size();
    }
}
```

This is code for MainActivity

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
EditText input;
ChatAdapter adapter;
ChatPresenter chatPresenter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_chat);
    input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_search_box);
    input.setOnEditorActionListener(searchListener);
    this.chatPresenter=new ChatPresenter();
    chatPresenter.attachView(this);
    this.adapter=new ChatAdapter(chatPresenter.getChatObjects());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
}
```

So how to set LayoutManager as a Horizontal for different ViewType ?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you are trying to do? You cannot have two different layout managers in one `RecyclerView` since a list cannot scroll both horizontally and vertically at the same time. Are you trying to create a 2d list?

Comment: Yes.I want the Same Recyclerview Entry that can scroll Horizontally  when I have multiple card views in Recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be achieved by overriding getItem(int position) method in your adapter and calling a callback in your activity/fragment. which will set different layout managers.

Answer (score -1):

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));

use this to make recyclerview with horizontal view.

Comment: is this useful for you ?